# Syncronisation between printing odd and even number via threading

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code will show output as

```
0 1 3 2 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Unable to judge the error. We wanted to get the output as

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

from time import sleep

mylock1 = Lock()
#mylock2 = Lock()

def evenprint ( uservalue):#dunder __init__
    for i in range(0,uservalue,2):
        sleep(1)
        mylock1.acquire(True)
        print(i,end=' ')
        mylock1.release()
def oddprint(uservalue):
    for i in range(1,uservalue,2):
        sleep(1)
        mylock1.acquire(True)
        print(i,end=' ')
        mylock1.release()

variable=21
t1= Thread(target=evenprint,args=(variable,))
t2= Thread(target=oddprint,args=(variable,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: `range(0,uservalue,2)` starts with a 0. So, 0 is the first value of `i`. Why would you expect it not to be printed? BTW, the two functions differ only in 0/1. Must be one function with two parameters.

Comment: I agree with DYZ

Comment: DYZ, apologies, I need the sequential output.. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 but the output is not coming as sequence.. In short, I want even and odd output display 1 after other.. 0(evn) 1(odd) 2(even) and so on..